# How to get the list of online users in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How do I get the list online users in Yii2 application? I use membership, and want to get list of online users to show to admin in control panel.

Is there any way to get the list of ALL logged-in users ?

Thanks!
Best regards

Comment: Too broad. Where's your attempt (if you made one)? I can only suggest how to make one but might be not the best solution. Since this might take a lot of space (code and how well we would go), I would suggest to send me an email.

Comment: thanks for your answer 
i sanded an email to you

Answer (score 3):

It's not easy because of the nature of PHP (stateless). You need to store the list of such users and keep it up to date.

I use the following approach:

1. Save timestamp in users database every time user makes action.
2. List of users that made an action in last 5 minutes is the list of online
   users.

Of course this is just an approximation:

- User can read single page for more than 5 minutes and so not counts
  as online although he is.
- User can log out in less than 5 minutes and still counts as online.
- Changing the 5 minutes timer does not fix the problems.

If you want more precise results more sophisticated methods are needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need some simple code for that

Comment: As I said it's not straightforward.

Comment: i know and it`s the problem